# Broadcasting to specific values only (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array like so:

```
array([[  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ],
       [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
       [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
       [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
       [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
       [  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ]])
```

Is there a way to broadcast another array onto this array only to specific values, e.g. cells where the value is 1?

For example, if I wanted to broadcast the following array onto the one above,

```
array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33])
```

Then I would be hoping for the following output:

```
array([[  0,  0, 10, 11,  0,  0 ],
       [  0, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0 ],
       [ 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 ],
       [ 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27 ],
       [  0, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0 ],
       [  0,  0, 32, 33,  0,  0 ]])
```

Since the arrays have incompatible shapes, this may not be achievable strictly with broadcasting, but I'd like to have a vectorized method to accomplish this if possible.

It would also be fine to use a `masked_array` data structure if there is a way to do that, but I haven't found anything in the documentation yet to suggest that there are built-in methods for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing for that:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mask = np.array([[  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ],
...        [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
...        [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
...        [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
...        [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
...        [  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ]])
>>> values = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33])
>>> out = np.zeros(mask.shape, values.dtype)
>>> out[mask.astype(bool)] = values
>>> out
array([[ 0,  0, 10, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [ 0, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 32, 33,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I needed, thanks for the tip. Looks like this is a whole new dimension of numpy for me to explore.

Answer (score 1):

its actually a 1 line solution

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ],
   [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
   [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
   [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
   [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
   [  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ]])

xs = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33])

arr[arr==1] = xs
arr
# outputs
array([[ 0,  0, 10, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
       [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27],
       [ 0, 28, 29, 30, 31,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 32, 33,  0,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

For numpy arrays you can use conditions to slice the array to do so for your example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
   [  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ],
   [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
   [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
   [  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1 ],
   [  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0 ],
   [  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0 ]])

b = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
              17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
              24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
              31, 32, 33])

# all elements of a should be the elements of b
a[a==1] = b  # the number of ones in a must match the length of b
print(a)

[[ 0  0 10 11  0  0]
[ 0 12 13 14 15  0]
[16 17 18 19 20 21]
[22 23 24 25 26 27]
[ 0 28 29 30 31  0]
[ 0  0 32 33  0  0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be dangerous to do because you need to assume that you have the same number of values in y as there are 1's in x.

Given that this is true then you can do the following

```
count = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[i])):
        if x[i][j] == 1:
            x[i][j] = y[count]
            count += 1
```